# Need help determining if SQL*PLUS procedure call is correct (PHP)

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

my professor asked us to do a project using PHP and SQL (Oracle) and  I've never done PHP before in class or outside of it. I keep getting an error on the execute line that says my inputs are not correct. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the input area, or is there something else wrong. I'm trying to execute a stored procedure.(Error code is ORA-06550).

```
function makeReservation($conn, $roomNo, $custID, $cardNo, $startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime){
    $procedure = oci_parse($conn, 'BEGIN makeReservation(:roomNo, :custID, :cardNo, TO_DATE(:startDate, \'month dd YYYY\'), :startTime, TO_DATE(:endDate, \'month dd YYYY\'), :endTime);  END;');
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':roomNo', $roomNo);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':custID', $custID);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':cardNo', $cardNo);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':startDate', $startDate);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':startTime', $startTime);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':endDate', $endDate);
    oci_bind_by_name($procedure, ':endTime', $endTime);
    oci_execute($procedure);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact text of the error. Also, please include the source code of the stored procedure you're calling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see nothing about SQL*Plus

1/ You should add a return clause to your php function
2/ Maybe try  "'BEGIN makeReservation(:roomNo, :custID, :cardNo, TO_DATE(:startDate, 'month dd YYYY', :startTime, TO_DATE(:endDate, 'month dd YYYY'), :endTime);  END;") 
3/ De sure than :startDate and :endDate are in a correct format
4/ May be add a fourth parameter $maxlength = -1 for each bind